# Javascript looping through an JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through a JSON array that looks like the following -

```js
var results = [{"city_name":"Bradford","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberdeen","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberfeldy","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberaeron","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberdare","counter":0},{"city_name":"Abergavenny","counter":0},{"city_name":"Abergele","counter":0}];

for(var i = 0; i  < results.length; i++) {
    var obj = results[i];                   
    console.log(obj.city_name);
    console.log(obj.counter);
}
```

but all I get is undefined in the alert.

Comment: Just type `console.log(typeof results)` and tell us what you received.

Comment: your code seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working

```js
let results=[{"city_name":"Bradford","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberdeen","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberfeldy","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberaeron","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberdare","counter":0},{"city_name":"Abergavenny","counter":0},{"city_name":"Abergele","counter":0}]


for(var i = 0; i  < results.length; i++) {
    var obj = results[i];                   
    console.log(obj.city_name);
    console.log(obj.counter);
}
//second way
results.forEach(a=>{
console.log(a.city_name);
    console.log(a.counter);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly understand you but maybe it's hepls

```js
const results = [{"city_name":"Bradford","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberdeen","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberfeldy","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberaeron","counter":1},{"city_name":"Aberdare","counter":0},{"city_name":"Abergavenny","counter":0},{"city_name":"Abergele","counter":0}]

for(let i in results) {
    console.log("city_name",results[i].city_name); 
    console.log("counter",results[i].counter);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works. But better to write it like this:

```
results.forEach(result => alert(result.city_name));
```

In any case, it should work even with your syntax.

Comment: why is it better to write it like that when `.forEach` takes longer to run? What advantages does your alternative way give

Comment: Nick, just because it is always good practice to reduce lines of code you use in your application due to many reasons.

Comment: I wouldn't say it always is "good practice". Sometimes reducing the lines of code can result in maintainability issues and such :/

Comment: Nick, I'm only beginner and sharing what I know :) Good to have your opinion as well.

Comment: Yes yes, no worries, It's always good to share your ideas and thoughts :) just informing you :D

Comment: Ok, great! :) I also always thought that it is better if your code clean and as much dry as possible. You would not recommend .forEach?

Comment: `.forEach` is fine to use when you don't have large sets of data (as `.forEach` is slower than using a regular for loop). Your example is fine :)